# Overriding a Laravel Eloquent Model in an accessor returns 0 on using a property

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent, accessor

Sorry for the (maybe) somewhat unclear questioning. I didn't know how to put it in any other way. (suggestions are welcome :p) The code however speaks for itself I think:

I'm using an accessor to get the Theme of a Page (or from its parent if it doesn't have a theme set) as such:

```
public function getThemeAttribute()
{
    if(!isset($this->theme_uid) || $this->theme_uid === null || $this->theme_uid === '')
    {
        return $this->parent->theme()->first();
    }

    //return $this->theme->first();
    return self::theme()->first();
}
```

This does work if I'm requesting the theme property itself eg.:

```
$page->theme
```

Which returns:

```
Theme {#741 ▼ ...etcetera
```

But if I try to access a property on the returned model eg:

```
$page->theme->uid
```

I get:

```
0
```

Probably has something to do with what happens under the hood, but haven't figured it out yet, so any help would be great.

Thanks already!

Regards Gijs

Comment: If I understand your code correctly it should end up in a loop since you are using the getThemeAttribute but also use $this->theme in the same function which both reference the same function.

Comment: @Gijs Beijer I posted a few ideas. Also, for why you are getting `0` for the uuid, could you do this test? `dd($theme->getAttributes());`

Comment: I @milo526 You where right I copied tryout code, i actually used self::theme() to overcome this, which does return me the correct Theme model instance but i cant call any attributes.

Comment: @Andrius Rimkus, calling: `->getAttributes()` does show me the values

Comment: If you are seeing `uuid` in the raw attributes array, then the issue is probably related to `uuid` accessor.

Comment: no `uuid` in the array

Comment: is `uuid` set as the primaryKey? if so is it set to not be autoincrementing on the model?  (casting concern: `(int)"something" === 0`)

Comment: no, the primarykey is called 'id' and is an unsigned integer :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so as a small code improvement:

```
(!isset($this->theme_uid) || $this->theme_uid === null) === !isset($this->theme_uid)
```

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

Now this part:

```
return $this->theme->first();
```

Will lead to magic method `__get` recursion and throw an exception.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71254

In your case, `theme` is a relationship, not an attribute. I think `attribute` accessors should be used for their intended purpose - `attribute` access mutation. You could express your situation via custom relationship:

```
public function availableTheme()
{
    if(!empty($this->theme_uid))
    {
        return $this->theme();
    }

    return $this->parent->theme();
}

// $page->availableTheme
// $page->avalaibleTheme()->where(...)->first()
```

Comment: hi your availableTheme() method does work but it leaves me with an ugly syntax in the views where I would really want it to be intuitive for the rest of the team.
I will edit my question with the method I used now (incorporating `->getAttributes()` as @Andrius Rimkus suggested

Comment: The naming is up to you. Just wanted to address what is the issue to my mind - setting accessor for the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the method I went with is the following:

```
public function getThemeAttribute()
{
    if(!isset($this->theme_uid) || $this->theme_uid === null || $this->theme_uid === '')
    {
        return (object)$this->parent->theme()->first()->getAttributes();
    }

    return (object)self::theme()->first()->getAttributes();
}
```

This allows me to have a nice syntax where I need to access the values (eg: `$page->theme->uid` or `$page->theme->color` without having to worry if it is on the parent or what kind of type (`Relation`, `Model`, etc) the returned value on theme is.

If somebody can tell me why this isn't directly possible I'm still very interested, and anybody who helped here: Thanks!